# How can I write a react component that has dependent props in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I write Typescript types for a React component where the value of one of the props depends on the value of another prop?

I am trying to write an `Icon` component that looks up the SVG path for an icon from a pre-defined map.  The map is nested such that the top-level properties are the icon styles.  Each of those styles has its own map where the properties are the icon names.  Like this:

```
const icons = {
  regular: {
    check: '',
  },
  solid: {
    on: '',
  },
};
```

The component takes a prop `$flair` which is the icon style and `$name` which is the icon name.  I need these two props to be related such that the values of `$name` are limited to the icons of this `$flair`.  If `$flair` is `'regular'` then `$name` can be `'check'` but it cannot be `'on'`.

Here is what I have to so far:

```
type Icons = typeof icons;
type FlairNames = keyof Icons;
type IconNames = keyof Icons['regular'] | keyof Icons['solid'];

type Test = Extract<IconNames, keyof Icons['regular']>;

interface IconProps<F extends FlairNames> {
  $size?: number;
  $flair: F;
  $name: Extract<IconNames, keyof Icons[F]>;
}

function IconImpl({
  $size,
  $flair,
  $name,
}: IconProps<'regular'> | IconProps<'solid'>): JSX.Element {
  const flair = icons[$flair];
  const d = flair[$name];

  return (
    <svg>
      <path d={d} />
    </svg>
  );
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlqSMC8MDeAoGMBOBTAcwFcAbAQxwC50tsZgALPYAa2oHJ2AaWgXx%20wQQJOABNqmOjHAdufHrwDcGDFACeABzwwAkoggoY6rSABm8fcuPaAYuTg4AcmQC2eA6hZ41Z3ZdWa2nrgzm4eMF4%205sGQANrs%20MTkOOwAujAAPhHevjEQ8UIiomnKAVowACrusKgAogAeUDhkwFAAPDGh7lzZUX7g%20QmEpBRpAHylcGBQeDimLUGIAAo4IBoQbTYweI14YKIGdmQOXRBjNNgAJBBwAF54APzUYEQuAEazylem9lQwNl8YJcwK48NQGk0Wu1OqCID1Irl9LEbKkJhheCpTEQwK04OB%20mAdC4NCQABSSIE3e4CIE-Y44GnA0EKagxFZrDZDJKjc5ZNmrdZtdiFMTsMYASmoACkAMoADQAdLUSHg3NMLvQBrA6Q5DAgBrFLjqcKlAfpYKJDMbDSC3KaVNh8FAiDgwDBSbRsG0IAA3AhjT10NoaMhQBgwUTINCiXgwAD0AakbTjvv9tHFygxQA)

I'd like to be able to use the component as follows:

```
<Icon $flair="regular" $name="check" />
<Icon $flair="solid" $name="on" />
<Icon $flair="regular" $name="does-not-exist" /> // error
<Icon $flair="regular" /> // error
<Icon $name="on" /> // error
```

Comment: I can def help you type this but what is the purpose of the $ in the prop names?

Answer (score 2):

#### With a Union

When you have two props that need to be a matching pair it's actually better (in my opinion) to use a union of all valid pairs instead of a generic.  When you have `F extends FlairNames` the value of `F` can be the union (`'regular' | 'solid'`) so we can't actually *guarantee* a match.

You can compute those matching pairs by using a mapped type:

```
type PossiblePairings = {
  // for each flair type (regular/solid)
  [FlairName in keyof Icons]: {
    // expect the prop flair to be this flair name
    $flair: FlairName,
    // and the prop name to be one of the keys of this flair object
    $name: keyof Icons[FlairName];
  }
  // access by keyof icon to flatten the map into a union
}[keyof Icons]
```

This resolves to the union:

```
type PossiblePairings = {
    $flair: "regular";
    $name: "check";
} | {
    $flair: "solid";
    $name: "on";
}
```

So now we include this type in `IconProps`, which is no longer a generic.

```
type IconProps = {
  $size?: number;
} & PossiblePairings;
```

We do have to make one `as` assertion in the implementation.  Typescript doesn't quite understand that our second-level key is always a property of the first key's object.  So we get an error on accessing `flair[$name]`:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"check" | "on"' can't be used to index type '{ check: string; } | { on: string; }'.
>
> Property 'check' does not exist on type '{ check: string; } | { on: string; }'

```
function Icon({
  $size,
  $flair,
  $name,
}: IconProps): JSX.Element {
  const flair = icons[$flair];
  const d = (flair as Record<string, string>)[$name];

  return (
    <svg>
      <path d={d} />
    </svg>
  );
}
```

This works with all your test cases:

```
<Icon $flair="regular" $name="check" />
<Icon $flair="solid" $name="on" />

<Icon $flair="regular" $name="on" /> // error
<Icon $flair="solid" $name="check" /> // error

<Icon $flair="regular" $name="does-not-exist" /> // error
<Icon $flair="regular" /> // error
<Icon $name="on" /> // error
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Wyv5gw)

#### With Generics

The code you had before is like 90% there already, but could use a few improvements:

- it has the same error on `flair[$name]` that the union types did.
- `Extract<IconNames, keyof Icons[F]>` is the same as just `keyof Icons[F]`
- We would prefer not to type out all of the flair types in `IconProps<'regular'> | IconProps<'solid'>`, so we should make the component be a generic which is dependent on the flair type and say that the props are `IconProps<F>`.
- After making those changes, the error on `flair[$name]` goes away, but now there is an error further down on `<path d={d} />`

This revised version should work:

```
type FlairNames = keyof Icons;

interface IconProps<F extends FlairNames> {
  $size?: number;
  $flair: F;
  $name: keyof Icons[F];
}

function Icon<F extends FlairNames>({
  $size,
  $flair,
  $name,
}: IconProps<F>): JSX.Element {
  const flair = icons[$flair];
  const d = flair[$name] as unknown as string;

  return (
    <svg>
      <path d={d} />
    </svg>
  );
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/W44pBW)

Comment: I like solution with unions. It makes illegal state unrepresentable